# Visual Studio 2008 imports WSDL with wrong data type

Tags: visual-studio-2008, data-structures, wsdl

I'm trying to use a web service and thus added a web service reference to my project using the service's WSDL service description. All is well, there were no error message, but I noticed that one field is declared as `string` in my web service reference while it should be `int`.

Going through the WSDL service description, I noticed that the respective field is declared as:

```
<xsd:complexType name="ItemType">
    <xsd:all>
        <xsd:element name="quantity" type="xsd:integer"/>
    </xsd:all>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Obviously, the field is supposed to be an integer, but Visual Studio 2008 thinks that it is a string.

My questions are:

1. Is `xsd:integer` a valid WSDL data type or shouldn't it be `xsd:int`?
2. How can I tell VS 2008 that this field should be `int`?
3. Will I still be able to use the service when I provide a `string` (only containing numbers) in C# where the caller (obviously a PHP script) expects an `int`?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trouble is: `xs:integer` is "signed integer of arbitrary length" - so it could be larger than the .NET Int32 type's range --> thus it's converted to string by VS2008.

Use `xs:int` - I believe that's being converted to Int32 properly.

See here: http://www.codesynthesis.com/projects/xsd/documentation/schema-authoring-guide.xhtml#integer

`xs:int` maps to 32-bit integer, while `xs:integer` is of arbitrary length.

> Will I still be able to use the service when I provide a string (only
>   containing numbers) in C# where the
>   caller (obviously a PHP script)
>   expects an int?

I would say yes, because in the end, the message going across the wire will always be textual XML at its core. It doesn't really care whether you supply a string "12345" and serialize that into your XML message, or whether you serialize '12345' as an INT into the message - in XML, in the end, everything is a string.

Marc

Comment: Thanks for that - I'll post this information to the web service provider.

Comment: Will I still be able to communicate with the web service properly (see my question #2)?